# Как при вызове хранимой процедуры получить значение переданное в RETURN

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Допустим имеем произвольную хранимую процедуру, для чистоты эксперимента возьмем тривиальный вариант:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetAnswer
AS
RETURN 42
```

и код ее вызова на C#

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.GetAnswer";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Как получить возвращаемое значение?

Замена `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` на `cmd.ExecuteScalar();` не поможет, т.к. `ExecuteScalar` возвращает `null` для такой процедуры.

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/q/6210027/5796587

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ответ оказался для меня совсем не очевидным.

В коде будет выглядеть так:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //начало не меняется
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.GetAnswer";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //Добавляем параметр к вызову процедуры (имя значения не имеет)
    //Стоп, но у нашей процедуры нет параметров???
    var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
    //Обратите внимание на значение Direction
    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    //выполняем тоже как обычно
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //забираем значение
    int answer = (int)returnParameter.Value;
}
```

В общем то ничего сложного, но последнее чего я ожидал, это добавление несуществующего параметра.

Отдельно замечу, никаких изменений в хранимой процедуре делать не требуется. **Добавляемый в команду параметр не является параметром процедуры.**

Хранимая процедура всегда возвращает какое-то целочисленное значение. Если ни одного RETURN с явным указанием значения в процедуре нет, возвращается 0.