# Как в wfa приложении С# выполнить SQL скрипт?

Tags: c#, sql

C простыми SQL запросами всё понятно,

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("строка соединения");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from z_test", conn);
```

а как вот такой текст туда добавить?

```
declare @a int
        @b int

exec @val = Object_Int
        @ew = 0
        @rt = @er

select @val
,@er
```

Comment: вас интересует вызов хранимых процедур?

Comment: @rdom, если реализуется через их вызов, то да

Comment: посмотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/639982/198316 там вызов процедуры без параметров, но параметры добавляются легко, и в MSDNпримеры есть для класса SqlCommand

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативный способ запуска скриптов - это использовать [SMO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/create-program/creating-smo-programs). Через него можно запускать скрипты как в Management Studio.

```
//Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
//Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteWithResults(script);
```